# create UITableView in iPad using Monodevelop C#

Tags: c#, ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three iPad application in `objective c` using `Xcode 4`.

but now i want to create iPad application using `Monodeveloper tool` in `C#` language...

for that i need some basic tutorial, which implements `UITableView`,

i searched in google but i didn't got any tutorial.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough a simple googling for "Monotouch tutorials" would get you started easily, here are some places to begin with:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios

http://ios.xamarin.com/Tutorials

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples

http://monotouchexamples.com/

Especially for tables, you should consider Monotouch.Dialog: 
https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog